# Getting JsonSyntaxException in Android retrofit response?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

Related [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201851/how-to-parse-newline-delimited-json-response-in-android)

Response of `Json` is `New line delimiter Json` :

```
{"type":"data","id":"xyz"}
{"type":"value","id":"xcf"}
....
....
```

I am using `Retrofit` to make request:

```
public void getWarehouse(){

 //Generation of  RestAdapter
 RestAdapter adapter = new  RestAdapter.Builder ()
            .setEndpoint(URL)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setLog(new AndroidLog("= NETWORK ="))
            .build();

 //Making request to API
 adapter.create(WarehouseAPI.class).getWarehouse()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Observer<Response>() {
         @Override
         public void onCompleted() {
             Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "OnCompleted ()");
         }

         @Override
         public void onError(Throwable e) {
             Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Error:"  + e.toString());
         }

         @Override
         public void onNext(Response response) {
         System.out.println("test");

         }


       });

}
```

I can see the response in my `Android Studio console` but getting following error:

`Error:retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 2 column 2 path $`

## Possibility of Error

- Response is in `NdJson` and it's not able to parse it correctly

## Question

- How can I parse it correctly?

Comment: Are you trying to read it as an array? Should your response be wrapped in []?

Comment: @trevor-e No actually it's `NdJson`. So No `JsonArray` or `JsonObject` will work here . Please have a look at this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121584/how-to-parse-a-large-newline-delimited-json-file-by-jsonstream-module-in-node-j

(If I am not wrong)

Comment: I see. I believe you will need to specify a customer converter to retrofit to handle that, possibly using a custom Gson object.

Comment: I don't have enough experience in `retrofit` but is it possible to get response in any form. I mean can I get the response as it is from the request through above code (because I can see the data coming through retrofit in my studio console)

Answer (score 0):

As @trevor-e mentions, you have to implement a custom converter to handle the ndjson format. Check link below for a guide to start:

[Retrofit — Define a Custom Response Converter](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-replace-the-integrated-json-converter/)

Also check out the StringConverter from: [How can I return String or JSONObject from asynchronous callback using Retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881943/how-can-i-return-string-or-jsonobject-from-asynchronous-callback-using-retrofit)

You could potentially convert the response to a regular string then parse each line into a JSON object and proceed from there.